# getting errors The POST method

Tags: laravel, post, controller, get

I have a problem with my edit page. When I submit I get this error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>
> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> POST

.

I have no clue where it comes from as I am pretty new to Laravel.

web.php

```
Route::post('/admin/add_reseller','ResellerController@addReseller');
```

Controller.php

```
  public function addReseller(){
         return view ('admin.resellers.add_reseller');

    }
```

add_reseller.blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" name="addreseller" id="addreseller">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
```

Comment: Empty action `action=""`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tip:**

First of all, I would use named routes, that means you add `->name('someName')` to your routes. This makes the use of routes way easier and if you decide that your url doens't fit you don't need to change it everywhere you used the route.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes

```
e.g. Route::post('/admin/add_reseller',
'ResellerController@addReseller')->name('admin.reseller');
```

**Problem:**

What I see is, that you lack the value for the `action` attribute in your `<form>`. The action is needed, so that the right route is chosen, if the form gets submitted.

**Solution:**

I guess you just have to add `action="{{route('admin.reseller')}}"` for the attribute, so that the request goes the right route.

Comment: I have tried that and is not working either, I even clean the cache and still getting the same errors, any other idea!

Comment: did you also do `optimize:clear`, can you show your full web.php file?

Comment: yes i have tried that is same errors, also here is some codes in web.php 
Route::post('/admin/add_reseller','ResellerController@addReseller');
Route::get('/admin/view_reseller','ResellerController@viewReseller');
Route::get('/admin/edit_reseller','ResellerController@editReseller')
funny things is that the rest of code in web.php works fine with route::post, but this one is not. any idea.?

Comment: do you have some paramterized routes like: /admin/{something} or /{something}/add_reseller?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" name="addreseller" id="addreseller">
```

Your **action** in the `form` is empty, you need to add the corresponding route there.

I'd suggest you to use named routes.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes

In web.php

```
Route::post('/admin/add_reseller','ResellerController@addReseller')->name('admin.add.reseller');
```

and then in your blade file you could refer to the route using the `route()` function by passing the name of the route as an argument

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{route('admin.add.reseller')}}" name="addreseller" id="addreseller">
```

Comment: I have tried all above that and is not working, I'm getting same errors. any other idea!

Comment: Are you sure that the method in form is POST because this error suggests something else. `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST` This error means you're submitting a get request on a route that supports POST method.

Comment: As you can see the first message I posted above I copied that code line from the editor and posted it here, did I misspell?? Also please see the first line of the error message, does is this mean anything!!

Comment: That is the exception that was thrown and the message is what I explained to you earlier. Somehow GET request is being made to a route that supports POST. I'm not saying that what you pasted here is not right, I'm just explaining you the error, that this is what is happening. What you can try is add code in the script for that html page, that gets that particular form and then lists the action, method for that form, just so that you can verify it. This is just a way that you could do to debug. And in case you need any help with this let me know.